# Intellij: private interface methods are not supported in -source 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface

I am new to Java and am running it on Intellij. I am going through a tutorial and am able to run the class, the problem is when I try and compile the code I get the run error

`private interface methods are not supported in -source 8`

I believe I am running Java 14. Judging from other StackOverflow questions I can see that private interface methods have been allowed since Java 9. Can someone tell me the reason for this error?

Comment: check `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Project SDK` and `Project language level`

Comment: Yeah I've done that. But adding a properties section where I specified the maven compiler and maven compiler target actually worked. Thanks though!!

Comment: IntelliJ has been glitchy with compiler levels in Maven projects since at least Java 6; it's always good to check even when everything _should_ be working.